Uncertain serial autocorrelation in GAM count model residuals
I wish to use Generalised Additive Models (GAMs) to smooth count time series and estimate first derivatives, i.e. to identify periods where the counts are increasing, stable or decreasing.
I'm using R and have found serial autocorrelation in the residuals of mgcv::gam() models. Having low confidence in mgcv::gamm() for non-gaussian distributions plus serial autocorrelation (i.e. MASS::glmmPQL()), I turned to mvgam::mvgam(). The mvgam smooths are practically identical to those from gam yet the diagnostics for the mvgam models show no "significant" autocorrelation.
Here are some plots fot the example code at the bottom of this post (in order: gam smooth, mvgam smooth, mvgam diagnostics, gam acf(), mvgam acf()).





The acf() and pacf() plots for the gam model deviance residuals indicate negative "AR3" autocorrelation. The diagnostics for the mvgam model quantile residuals do not indicate negative autocorrelation, however the acf() and pacf () for the mean quantile residuals do!
Is there autocorrelation or is there not? Regarding the contradictory mvgam diagnostics, I suspect that acf(mean residuals) != mean(acf(residuals)).
I did try fitting mvgam with trend_model = "AR3" but those AR coefficients were imprecise and "not significant".
The gam model is fit for purpose because it's faster than mvgam, easier to extract the first derivatives and confidence intervals and I'm not interested in forecasts. However, if the acf() plots for the gam deviance residuals are reliable, it would be difficult to convince a peer that the confidence intervals are accurate.
To more thoroughly investigate serial autocorrelation, I have thought to simulate from the fitted gam to generate a distribution of acf() and pacf() coefficients (something like what mvgam has done). Perhaps those simulations would show that serial autocorrelation is most frequently within tolerance. I'm not sure how to code that.
library("mgcv") # mgcv_1.9-1
library("rstan") # rstan_2.32.6; cmdstanr didn't work for me
library("mvgam") # mvgam_1.1.3
library("gratia") # gratia_0.9.2
## data
# some annual counts and populations (100,000s)
# the idea is to model the rate = count / 100,000 population
# n = 29 is a short time series
dat <- data.frame(time = 1996:2024,
  count = c(314, 590, 725, 953, 1218, 1688, 2227, 2751,
  3395, 4189, 4865, 5650, 5829, 6664, 7097, 8078, 8720,
  9455, 9773, 10382, 10519, 10576, 10814, 11904, 13176,
  14631, 15075, 16282, 17371),
pop = c(23.48816, 23.81456, 24.08718, 24.39848, 24.71095,
  25.08078, 25.35108, 25.59605, 25.78745, 26.0291, 26.2812,
  26.66912, 27.13734, 27.61413, 28.0111, 28.35941, 28.73572,
  29.17764, 29.64432, 30.10587, 30.59446, 31.10672, 31.52141,
  31.9123, 32.20657, 32.11941, 32.41207, 33.22432, 34.03657))
## gam model (with negative binomial error distribution)
mod1 <- gam(count ~ offset(log(pop)) + s(time, k=10),
  data = dat, family = nb())
summary(mod1) # nb theta = 2715.554
png(filename="mod1diag.png")
  gam.check(mod1) # diagnostics OK
dev.off()
## mvgam model
mod2 <- mvgam(count ~ offset(log(pop)) + s(time, k=10),
  data = dat, family = nb())
summary(mod2, include_betas=FALSE) # nb theta = 1800
png(filename="mod2diag.png")
  plot(mod2, type="residuals") # autocorrelation within tolerance
dev.off()
## fitted smooths
png(filename="mod1smooth.png")
  draw(mod1)
dev.off()
png(filename="mod2smooth.png")
  drawDotmvgam(mod2)
dev.off()
## gam deviance residuals; acf practically identical type="pearson"
r1 <- residuals(mod1, type="deviance")
png(filename="mod1acf.png")
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
  acf(r1, main="gam deviance residuals")
  pacf(r1)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))  
dev.off()
## mvgam mean (or median) residuals contradict the acf plots above
r2 <- residuals(mod2)[, 1]
png(filename="mod2acf.png")
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
  acf(r2, main="mvgam mean quantile residuals")
  pacf(r2)  
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
dev.off()

Follow up
The title to this question says it all.
Below are some more plots:

mvgam (k=14, no ar) mean quantile residuals versus gam (k = 14) deviance residuals.
mvgam mean acf() and 95% interval versus acf(mean).
A variation on the mvgam ACF diagnostics plot.

I computed the acf() distributions from mvgam::residuals(summary=FALSE), which extracts the posterior draws of the quantile residuals.
The gam deviance residuals are OK (first plot below). The problem is that the acf() from those point estimates appears to be unreliable (second and third plots below), i.e. mean acf() is not equal to acf(mean); the latter tends to overestimate the magnitude of the autocorrelation.
I hope to be able to apply mgcv::simulate() to simulate gam residuals and acfs to make inference about serial autocorrelation in gams more reliable.
Finally, the time series is short and the mvgam models were inconclusive about the presence of serial autocorrelation in the residuals:

The raw data (counts and rates) show positive serial autocorrelation.
The mod2 (no ar) diagnostics show scattered and "weak" negative serial autocorrelation with wide intervals, i.e. the smooth has effectively eliminated the positive serial autocorrelation.
The ar3 model estimates suggest "weak" positive serial autocorrelation with wide intervals. Unsurprisingly, some priors had to be adjusted to fit the ar3 model to this short time series. There are a lot of "moving parts" (the smooth, the nb() error distribution and the ar(p = 3) serial correlation) and I have concerns about confounding.

Smooth and slope estimates (taking into account positive serial autocorrelation) from the ar3 model are wider than those from mod2 (no ar). On the other hand, if there is some residual negative serial autocorrelation for mod2 (no ar) then those intervals are conservative. My choice is the simpler model.




Your mvgam model doesn't have any autoregressive components in it, so these two models should be roughly equivalent apart from the better handling of uncertainties in mvgam. But there are a few tweaks you can include in this type of model to get better behaviours, mostly by regularizing the latent autoregressive process so it doesn't compete too much with the temporal smooth. Below are a few suggestions, but either way I wouldn't put too much faith into interpreting residual autocorrelation tests for such a short time series
library("mgcv") # mgcv_1.9-1
library("mvgam") # mvgam_1.1.4 (current Github version)
library("gratia") # gratia_0.9.2
library("ggplot2") # ggplot2 3.5.1
theme_set(theme_bw())

# The data
dat <- data.frame(time = 1996:2024,
                  count = c(314, 590, 725, 953, 1218, 1688, 2227, 2751,
                            3395, 4189, 4865, 5650, 5829, 6664, 7097, 8078, 8720,
                            9455, 9773, 10382, 10519, 10576, 10814, 11904, 13176,
                            14631, 15075, 16282, 17371),
                  pop = c(23.48816, 23.81456, 24.08718, 24.39848, 24.71095,
                          25.08078, 25.35108, 25.59605, 25.78745, 26.0291, 26.2812,
                          26.66912, 27.13734, 27.61413, 28.0111, 28.35941, 28.73572,
                          29.17764, 29.64432, 30.10587, 30.59446, 31.10672, 31.52141,
                          31.9123, 32.20657, 32.11941, 32.41207, 33.22432, 34.03657))

# mvgam model with a few tweaks
mod2 <- mvgam(
  
  # Observation formula just contains the intercept and the offset
  count ~ offset(log(pop)),
  
  # State-Space parameterisation is usually more 
  # efficient as the smooths and the AR process operate
  # on the same level of the hierarchy; a b-spline with
  # varying penalty may be flexible enough to capture
  # most of the temporal evolution
  # https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2020/06/03/extrapolating-with-gams/
  trend_formula = ~ s(time, k = 14, bs = 'bs',
                      m = c(3, 2, 1)) - 1,
  
  trend_knots = list(time = c(1993, 1996, 2024, 2027)),
  
  # AR3 residual process
  trend_model = AR(p = 3),
  
  # Regularize the AR1 coefficient and variance
  # to make the smooth of time easier to estimate
  # (otherwise the AR1 may compete strongly by approaching
  # a flexible Random Walk behaviour)
  priors = c(prior(normal(0, 0.2),
                   class = ar1),
             prior(exponential(2),
                   class = sigma)),
  
  # Noncentred parameterisation often improves mixing for
  # latent stochastic parameters
  noncentred = TRUE,
  data = dat, 
  family = nb()
  )
#> Warning in smooth.construct.bs.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots): there is
#> *no* information about some basis coefficients
#> Warning in smooth.construct.bs.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots): there is
#> *no* information about some basis coefficients
#> Warning in smooth.construct.bs.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots): there is
#> *no* information about some basis coefficients
#> Compiling Stan program using cmdstanr
#> 
#> Start sampling
#> Running MCMC with 4 parallel chains...
#> 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 finished in 1.7 seconds.
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 finished in 2.1 seconds.
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 finished in 2.4 seconds.
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 finished in 3.5 seconds.
#> 
#> All 4 chains finished successfully.
#> Mean chain execution time: 2.4 seconds.
#> Total execution time: 3.7 seconds.

# Model summary
summary(mod2, include_betas = FALSE)
#> GAM observation formula:
#> count ~ offset(log(pop))
#> 
#> GAM process formula:
#> ~s(time, k = 14, bs = "bs", m = c(3, 2, 1)) - 1
#> 
#> Family:
#> negative binomial
#> 
#> Link function:
#> log
#> 
#> Trend model:
#> AR(p = 3)
#> 
#> 
#> N process models:
#> 1 
#> 
#> N series:
#> 1 
#> 
#> N timepoints:
#> 29 
#> 
#> Status:
#> Fitted using Stan 
#> 4 chains, each with iter = 1000; warmup = 500; thin = 1 
#> Total post-warmup draws = 2000
#> 
#> 
#> Observation dispersion parameter estimates:
#>        2.5% 50% 97.5% Rhat n_eff
#> phi[1]  140 780 13000    1   747
#> 
#> GAM observation model coefficient (beta) estimates:
#>             2.5% 50% 97.5% Rhat n_eff
#> (Intercept)  5.2 5.2   5.3 1.04    88
#> 
#> Process model AR parameter estimates:
#>          2.5%    50% 97.5% Rhat n_eff
#> ar1[1] -0.085  0.310  0.71 1.00   457
#> ar2[1] -0.410  0.240  0.65 1.03    91
#> ar3[1] -0.580 -0.095  0.48 1.01   447
#> 
#> Process error parameter estimates:
#>             2.5%   50% 97.5% Rhat n_eff
#> sigma[1] 0.00052 0.025 0.073 1.02   129
#> 
#> Approximate significance of GAM process smooths:
#>            edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
#> s(time) 0.0536     13   28.7 5.6e-07 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Stan MCMC diagnostics:
#> n_eff / iter looks reasonable for all parameters
#> Rhats above 1.05 found for 7 parameters
#>  *Diagnose further to investigate why the chains have not mixed
#> 132 of 2000 iterations ended with a divergence (6.6%)
#>  *Try running with larger adapt_delta to remove the divergences
#> 0 of 2000 iterations saturated the maximum tree depth of 10 (0%)
#> E-FMI indicated no pathological behavior
#> 
#> Samples were drawn using NUTS(diag_e) at Wed Nov 20 9:11:11 AM 2024.
#> For each parameter, n_eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
#> and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor on split MCMC chains
#> (at convergence, Rhat = 1)

# Plot the smooth using gratia::draw()
draw(mod2, trend_effects = TRUE)


# Plot the 1st derivative of the smooth using marginaleffects::plot_slopes()
plot_slopes(mod2, variables = 'time', 
            condition = 'time', type = 'link') +
  lims(y = c(-0.75, 0.75)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed')


# Or using mvgam's built-in plot function
plot(mod2, type = 'smooths', trend_effects = TRUE, derivatives = TRUE)


# Inspect residuals
plot(mod2, type = 'residuals')


# Inspect AR parameter estimates
mcmc_plot(mod2, variable = 'ar', 
          regex = TRUE, type = 'hist')
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.


mcmc_plot(mod2, variable = 'sigma', 
          regex = TRUE, type = 'hist')
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.


# Inspect hindcasts
hcs <- hindcast(mod2)
plot(hcs)


#> No non-missing values in test_observations; cannot calculate forecast score

# How would this model extrapolate?
newdat <- data.frame(time = 2025:2027,
                     pop = seq(34.6, 36, length.out = 3))
fcs <- forecast(mod2, newdata = newdat)
plot(fcs)
#> No non-missing values in test_observations; cannot calculate forecast score


Created on 2024-11-20 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks for pointing me towards marginal effects::slopes(). For the gam model, those estimates are identical to gratia::derivatives(interval="confidence").

Fitting AR3 with the small sample size is difficult. I agree that we shouldn't make inferences from acf() and pacf() point estimates alone. That inference about serial autocorrelation in the GAM residuals could be improved by simulation? I will think more about coding that.

I get the advice about including AR in the model if in doubt (because the time series is short in this example). I can add that statistical tests for autocorrelation in general can be problematic, e.g. https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ljung_box_df.html recommended to look at the acf() instead.

I agree completely on that point. But I've edited my answer above to give some further suggestions that you could consider for this type of series. Hopefully that helps a bit

This is all helpful in getting me started with GAMs and mvgam specifically. Thanks.

No worries. You certainly want to use mean(acf(resids)) rather than acf(mean(resids)). The latter can induce spurious correlations due to the random nature of DS residuals
